# Arduino stuck when I disable Timer 2 Interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, lcd, interrupt, temperature-sensor

```
#define TIM2_EN() (TIMSK2 = 0x02)
#define TIM2_DIS() (TIMSK2 = 0x00)

//HEART SENSOR
// Include Libraries
#include "Arduino.h"

class PulseSensor
{
public:
  static void begin(int pulsePin);

  static volatile int BPM;           // used to hold the pulse rate
  static volatile int Signal;        // holds the incoming raw data
  static volatile int IBI;           // holds the time between beats, must be seeded!
  static volatile boolean QS;        // becomes true when Arduoino finds a beat.
};

// Pin Definitions
#define HEARTPULSE_PIN_SIG  A0

// Global variables and defines

// object initialization
PulseSensor heartpulse;

volatile int rate[10];                        // array to hold last ten IBI values
volatile unsigned long sampleCounter = 0;     // used to determine pulse timing
volatile unsigned long lastBeatTime = 0;      // used to find IBI
volatile int P =512;                          // used to find peak in pulse wave, seeded
volatile int T = 512;                         // used to find trough in pulse wave, seeded
volatile int thresh = 512;                    // used to find instant moment of heart beat, seeded
volatile int amp = 100;                       // used to hold amplitude of pulse waveform, seeded
volatile boolean firstBeat = true;            // used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM
volatile boolean secondBeat = false;          // used to seed rate array so we startup with reasonable BPM
volatile boolean Pulse = false;               // true when pulse wave is high, false when it's low
volatile int pulsePin;

volatile int PulseSensor::IBI = 600;          // holds the time between beats, must be seeded!
volatile int PulseSensor::BPM;                // used to hold the pulse rate
volatile int PulseSensor::Signal;             // holds the incoming raw data
volatile boolean PulseSensor::QS = false;     // becomes true when Arduino finds a beat

void PulseSensor::begin(int pPin)
{
  pinMode(pulsePin, INPUT);
  pulsePin = pPin;

  // Initializes Timer1 to throw an interrupt every 2ms.
  TCCR1A = 0x00;
  TCCR1B = 0x0C;  // CTC (Compare match mode) and ClockIO/256
  OCR1A = 0x7C;   // 2 ms
  TIMSK1 = 0x02;
  sei();             // MAKE SURE GLOBAL INTERRUPTS ARE ENABLED
}

// THIS IS THE TIMER 1 INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINE. 
// Timer 1 makes sure that we take a reading every 2 miliseconds
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect)
{                         // triggered when Timer1 counts to 124
  cli();                                      // disable interrupts while we do this
  PulseSensor::Signal = analogRead(pulsePin);              // read the Pulse Sensor 
  sampleCounter += 2;                         // keep track of the time in ms with this variable
  int N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;       // monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise

  //  find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
  if(PulseSensor::Signal < thresh && N > (PulseSensor::IBI/5)*3){       // avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI
    if (PulseSensor::Signal < T){                        // T is the trough
      T = PulseSensor::Signal;                         // keep track of lowest point in pulse wave 
    }
  }

  if(PulseSensor::Signal > thresh && PulseSensor::Signal > P){          // thresh condition helps avoid noise
    P = PulseSensor::Signal;                             // P is the peak
  }                                        // keep track of highest point in pulse wave

  //  NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
  // signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
  if (N > 250){                                   // avoid high frequency noise
    if ( (PulseSensor::Signal > thresh) && (Pulse == false) && (N > (PulseSensor::IBI/5)*3) )
    {        
      Pulse = true;                               // set the Pulse flag when we think there is a pulse
      PulseSensor::IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;         // measure time between beats in mS
      lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;               // keep track of time for next pulse

      if(secondBeat){                        // if this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE
        secondBeat = false;                  // clear secondBeat flag
        for(int i=0; i<=9; i++){             // seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup
          rate[i] = PulseSensor::IBI;                      
        }
      }

      if(firstBeat){                         // if it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE
        firstBeat = false;                   // clear firstBeat flag
        secondBeat = true;                   // set the second beat flag
        sei();                               // enable interrupts again
        return;                              // IBI value is unreliable so discard it
      }   


      // keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values
      word runningTotal = 0;                  // clear the runningTotal variable    

      for(int i=0; i<=8; i++){                // shift data in the rate array
        rate[i] = rate[i+1];                  // and drop the oldest IBI value 
        runningTotal += rate[i];              // add up the 9 oldest IBI values
      }

      rate[9] = PulseSensor::IBI;                          // add the latest IBI to the rate array
      runningTotal += rate[9];                // add the latest IBI to runningTotal
      runningTotal /= 10;                     // average the last 10 IBI values 
      PulseSensor::BPM = 60000/runningTotal;               // how many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
      PulseSensor::QS = true;                              // set Quantified Self flag 
      // QS FLAG IS NOT CLEARED INSIDE THIS ISR
    }                       
  }

  if (PulseSensor::Signal < thresh && Pulse == true){   // when the values are going down, the beat is over
    Pulse = false;                         // reset the Pulse flag so we can do it again
    amp = P - T;                           // get amplitude of the pulse wave
    thresh = amp/2 + T;                    // set thresh at 50% of the amplitude
    P = thresh;                            // reset these for next time
    T = thresh;
  }

  if (N > 2500){                           // if 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
    thresh = 512;                          // set thresh default
    P = 512;                               // set P default
    T = 512;                               // set T default
    lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;          // bring the lastBeatTime up to date        
    firstBeat = true;                      // set these to avoid noise
    secondBeat = false;                    // when we get the heartbeat back
  }

  sei();                                   // enable interrupts when youre done!
} // end isr

//LDR SENSOR
int sensorPin = A1; // select the input pin for LDR
int sensorValue = 0; // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

//LCD
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,20,4);  // set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display

//DHT
#include "dht.h"
int dht_apin = 2;  
dht DHT;

//HEART RATE SENSOR
unsigned long current_time,start_time=0;
int BPM,Interval;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(115200);
  heartpulse.begin(HEARTPULSE_PIN_SIG);
  delay(1500);
  lcd.init();          // initialize the lcd 
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("  INITIALISING");
  delay(2500);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print(" CHECKING HEART");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print(" RATE NOW......");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.clear();
}

void loop() {

  current_time = millis();
  if ( current_time-start_time < 30000 )  {
    BPM = heartpulse.BPM;
    Interval = heartpulse.IBI; 
    lcd.print(" SYNCHRONIZING  ");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("   BEATS:"); 
    lcd.print(BPM);
    lcd.clear();
  } else  {
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("BEATS PER MINUTE");
    lcd.setCursor(6,1);
    lcd.print(BPM); 
    Serial.print(BPM);
    Serial.println('b');
    delay(4000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(" BEAT INTERVAL  ");
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);
    lcd.print(Interval); 
    Serial.print(Interval);
    Serial.println('p');
    delay(4000);
    TIM2_DIS(); //Enable TIMER2 Interrupt
    DHT.read11(dht_apin); 
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("    HUMIDITY    ");
    lcd.setCursor(6,1);
    lcd.print(DHT.humidity);
    lcd.print("%");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.println('h');
    delay(4000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("  TEMPERATURE  ");
    lcd.setCursor(5,1);
    lcd.print(DHT.temperature);
    lcd.print("C");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature);
    Serial.println('t');
    TIM2_EN(); //Disable TIMER2 Interrupt
    delay(4000);  
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin); // read the value from the sensor
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("LIGHT INTENSITY");
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);
    lcd.print(sensorValue);
    Serial.print(sensorValue);
    Serial.println('l');
    delay(4000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print(" CHECKING HEART");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print(" RATE NOW......");
    delay(2000);  
    lcd.clear();
    start_time = millis();
  }
}
```

I am trying to run LDR,PULSE AND DHT11 sensor together. DHT11 was not giving out readings along with pulse sensor before so I searched stack exchange and found out this solution.

> [DHT11 and Pulse sensor incompatibility?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21489/dht11-and-pulse-sensor-incompatibility)

But now the problem is Arduino gets stuck at the line when I disable timer 2 interupt -

```
TIM2_EN(); //Disable TIMER2 Interrupt
```

Any solution?

Comment: are you sure that TIM2_EN() disables the interrupt? ......  what does TIM2_DIS() do?

Comment: I came up with this idea from here.  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/21489/dht11-and-pulse-sensor-incompatibility?noredirect=1&lq=1 The code given in this works with this solution but my code is stuck and it is not even reading values from DHT

Comment: If i remove this line the code isn't stuck anymore- TIM2_EN(); //Disable TIMER2 Interrupt....But still Arduino is not able to read values from DHT11.

Comment: I do not know, can you explain in detail.

Comment: why would an interrupt enable macro be called TIM2_DIS()? ..... why would the interrupt disable macro be called TIM2_EN()?  ....... perhaps you are turning on the interrupt and it causes the program to hang, so the problem may actually be in the ISR

Comment: From Github I got this - TIMSK2 = 0x02;     // ENABLE INTERRUPT ON MATCH BETWEEN TIMER2 AND OCR2A. What can I do to read values from DHT11 and pulse sensor in the same program?

Comment: look at the very first line of your sketch ..... that confirms that you are enabling the interrupt when you thought that you were disabling it ............... now your focus should be on the ISR() to figure out which part is causing the problem ..... perhaps the ISR is too long         ............... also quit asking `What can I do to read values from DHT11 and pulse sensor in the same program?` and start asking `what is causing the failure?`

Comment: Got the solution, I was accidentally enabling and disabling timer 2 interrupt when actually I was using timer 1 in my program. Now first I am preventing timer 1 interrupts with TIMSK1 = 0 before reading DHT and again enabling timer 1 with TIMSK1 = 0x02 . Thanks #jsotola for telling me to find the failure ! Anyone wants to add anything about interupts ?